# Dismissing the last tab ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController to which I add and remove UIViews without any issue in the following way:

**Adding**

```
FileTabViewController* newTab = [[FileTabViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"File" bundle:nil];
NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:bar.viewControllers];
[array addObject:newTab];
[bar setViewControllers:array animated:YES];
[bar setSelectedIndex:bar.viewControllers.count-1];
```

**Removing** (within FileTabViewConroller.m)

```
NSMutableArray* newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];
[newArray removeObject:self];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:newArray animated:YES];
```

This code does exactly as I'd expect but there's on anomaly which I cannot explain. When the app launches and the view controller array is empty (nil) then there are (as you'd expect) no views shown in the tab view controller. As I add views the tabs increase correctly, but when I remove the very last one (i.e. index 0 of count 1) then the view *appears* to stay loaded, the buttons and labels on the final tab remaining visible - there seems to be no way to remove everything back to the 'nil' state the app launches with - despite the fact that there aren't actually any tabs shown on the controller.

Launch (as you'd expect)

[image]

Opening and closing a tab (this is where I get confused) - you see the tab disappears but the view remains open...?

[image]

Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: Do you ever set newArray to be the tab bar controller's viewControllers array?

Comment: Yes, I just didn't include that line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a little test app, and I see the same behavior you're seeing. I don't know whether this is an unintended consequence of the way a tab bar controller removes controllers and views, or whether Apple intended for this to happen -- after all, why would you want a black screen? Something seems to be keeping a strong pointer to that last view controller, because if I have a button that removes the controller (and it's the last one), I can still click that button and get the action to happen. The first time I click it, the tab bar controller still lists that controller as the selected controller, but if I click again, the selected controller is nil, but my view controller still lives.

The solution to getting rid of the view is easy, just remove the view from its superview after you remove the last controller from the array.

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

However, this doesn't get rid of the view controller. Something is still holding a reference to it, and so far, I haven't found out what is doing that.

Comment: It's interesting isn't it! You're correct, removeFromSuperview does reset the view back to black as it were, thanks.

Comment: But, the more I think about this, maybe you're right, maybe the initial view shouldn't be a black screen at all, and therefore neither should the view after closing all the tabs - is that bad UI...?

Comment: Well it's not very inviting. I wondered originally why you wanted to do that. It's still an interesting question though.

Comment: I guess beacuse it opens with no tabs open so I wanted it to return to that state...?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this hypothesis, but I wonder if the `` `moreNavigationController `` is coming into play here. Check its value before adding any tabs, and again after removing the last tab. Also take a look at the `visibleViewController` property of both the `moreNavigationController` and the `UITabBarController`.

Comment: I suppose it's possible - but I'm literally opening and dismissing just one tab at the moment, so it seems unlikely, but I'll have a quick look.